# Coverity Emitted file count issue

Tags: maven, coverity

I am trying to run analyses on my java project using coverity. Building the project with maven. But when it comes to coverity analyses it founds just 5 units (source files) where the project contains around 280 source files.

Am I missing about maven config beside native build config ? For native build I am setting as `mvn -DskipTests install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coverity is unable to bind to aspect compiler for analysis. One wants to analyze just code quality needs to create another profile without aspect build plugin. But keep in mind that this build will only be for analysis. For product release one still needs to keep aspect if you use in your application.

Comment: What is "aspect compiler" and what is the actual solution?

Answer (score 1):

`mvn clean install`

If you omit the clean, then some files won't be rebuilt.  Which will cause them not to be analyzed and hence not appear.  Also, skipping tests will cause them to not be built as well.  Further pushing down the file count.

Comment: well the problem has been solved. it was an issue with aspect (spring aspect) it is also confirmed from Coverity team that coverity is unable to bind to aspect compiler. Since aspect compiles all required classes as soon as it finds them in annotations etc.. There is not that much classes left for defult compiler. Which results with 5 classes.